# tomcat 6 won't start because of heap size

Tags: java, linux, tomcat6

when I run

```
sh catalina.sh run
```

it gives error:

> > Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx6144M
> >     The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
> >     Could not create the Java virtual machine.

help..

Comment: Did you try with -Xmx1012M ?

Comment: 64 or 32 bit machines?

Comment: @venergiac: 32 bit machine

Comment: And ... that's why. A single 32bit process can't access that much memory.

Comment: @Swagatika: then it gives `Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified`

Comment: You cannot on 32 bit machine...see Brian response (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running a 32bit JVM and are exceeding 4096M

Or .. there's supposedly a case where the JVM can decide you'd never need that large of heap, but I've never run into it.

Comment: how much memory I should allocate? giving `-Xmx2048M` won't work either. `Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.`

Comment: You're the only one that can answer that. How much memory do you *have*? Keep in mind the JVM isn't the only thing running on the machine.